# Trouble with VBA Do While loop in macro to copy slide and change picture in powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am attempting my first macro in powerpoint. I am simply trying to copy a 'reference' slide and replace one picture. I will do this for all pictures in a folder. The script I have adds all the slides, but then adds all the pictures to the final slide. I don't understand why this is the case since the Duplicate Slide code and the Add Picture code are in the same while loop. Can someone tell me why?

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles() 
    Dim StrFile As String 
    Dim Folder As String 
    Dim sld As Slide 
    Dim referencesld As Slide 
    Set referencesld = ActivePresentation.Slides(1) 
    Dim i As Integer 
    Dim shp As Shape 
    i = 1 
    Folder = "c:\E1B8\ScriptTesting\MISC\PPT\SampleData2\" 
    StrFile = Dir(Folder & "*") 
    Set referencesld = ActivePresentation.Slides(1) 
    Set shp = referencesld.Shapes(5) 
    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0 
        Debug.Print Folder & StrFile 
        referencesld.Duplicate 
        i = i + 1 
        Set sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(i) 
        With shp 
            sld.Shapes.AddPicture(Folder & StrFile, msoFalse, msoTrue, .Left, .Top, .Width, .Height).IncrementRotation 360# 
        End With 
        sld.Shapes(5).Delete 
        StrFile = Dir 
    Loop 
End Sub
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable when duplicating the slide, forget the "i" variable, it is not needed:

delete the lines

```
referencesld.Duplicate 
i = i + 1 
Set sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(i)
```

An insert "Set sld = referencesld.Duplicate" in the place

```
...
Debug.Print Folder & StrFile
Set sld = referencesld.Duplicate
With shp
  sld.Shapes.AddPicture(Folder & StrFile, msoFalse, msoTrue, .Left, .Top, .Width, .Height).IncrementRotation 360#
End With
...
```

*Untested*

You can see "Duplicate" reference in http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/ff745804(v=office.15).aspx

Aside: I think it is weird to use the "with" keyword on the argument (shape) instead of the object you are working on (the slide).

[edited: Make it clear to understand what to do]

I hope to help.

Comment: What sort of variable is sld then? N/M apparently I don't have to declare it. This worked, thanks!

Comment: I don't really know these objects, but: the sld is the slide, the shp is the shape. It seems you created a new shape on the same position and dimension of shape 5 from first slide, and then deleted the shape 5 to remain only with the created one on his place.

Comment: Oh, now i got your comment! You already declared sld. I mean, on the asnwer, that you should delete three lines beggining with "referencesld.Duplicate" up to "Set sld = ..." and stay only with "Set sld = referencesld.Duplicate".

Comment: You are correct fbiazi. I add a new picture with the dimensions of a reference picture in the duplicated slide, and then delete the reference picture from the duplicated slide.